# Java swing error in Windows Server 2003

Tags: java, swing, listener, windows-server-2003, jcombobox

I am facing a weird issue where it seems that the `PropertyChange` event for a combobox is not getting fired in Windows Server 2003. I have made the application in Java Swing. When I run the application on other OS it seems to be working fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I never saw that on Win2003/2008 JRE6_XX_XXX, same for WinXP/Win7

Answer (score 2):

just my curiosity this code works on `WinXP/Win2003` and `Win7/Win2008` various `JRE6_XX_XXX`, can you please put there your workaround for `JComboBox`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestPropListener {

    private static final Color TRUE_COLOR = new Color(180, 200, 255);
    protected static final Color FALSE_COLOR = new Color(255, 100, 100);

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        final MyBean panel = new MyBean();
        panel.setTitle(true);
        //panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        panel.setBackground(TRUE_COLOR);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                panel.setTitle(!panel.getTitle());
            }
        });
        panel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(MyBean.TITLE_PROP_NAME)) {
                    panel.setBackground(panel.getTitle() ? TRUE_COLOR : FALSE_COLOR);
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Property Listener");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private TestPropListener() {
    }
}

class MyBean extends JPanel {

    public final static String TITLE_PROP_NAME = "title";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean title;
    private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public boolean getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(boolean title) {
        boolean old = this.title;
        this.title = title;
        this.pcs.firePropertyChange(TITLE_PROP_NAME, old, title);
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```